# Proving that a convex combination of any distinct optimal solutions of a linear program is itself a solution

Tags: solution-verification, linear-programming

We are given the following linear program:
$$\text{Maximize } \vec{c} \vec{x}$$
$$\text{Subject to } A \vec{x}=\vec{b}$$
$$\vec{x} \ge 0$$

We wish to prove that any convex combination of two optimal solutions, say $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$, is itself an optimal solution.

Proof:
We know that $\vec{c} \vec{y}=\vec{c}\vec{z}=\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the value of the maximized objective function.
Now consider a convex combination of $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$:
$$\vec{w}=\lambda\vec{y}+(1-\lambda)\vec{z}, \lambda \in (0,1)$$
Consider now $\vec{c}\vec{w}$, we wish to find the value of this.
$$\vec{c}\vec{w} = \vec{c}(\lambda\vec{y}+(1-\lambda)\vec{z})$$
$$\vec{c}\vec{w} = \lambda\vec{c}\vec{y}+\vec{c}\vec{z}-\lambda\vec{c}\vec{z}$$
But we know that $\vec{c} \vec{y}=\vec{c}\vec{z}=\alpha$. Then,
$$\vec{c}\vec{w} = \vec{c}\vec{z}=\alpha$$
Hence $\vec{w}$ must be an optimal solution as required.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Is my proof that any convex combination of optimal solutions is itself an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the objective value of $\vec{w}$ is optimal, but you also need to show that $\vec{w}$ is feasible to both the linear constraints ($A\vec{w}=\vec{b}$) and the lower bounds ($\vec{w}\ge 0$).

\begin{align}
cw &= c(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z) = \lambda cy+(1-\lambda)cz = \lambda \alpha +(1-\lambda)\alpha = \alpha \\
Aw &= A(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z) = \lambda Ay+(1-\lambda)Az = \lambda b +(1-\lambda)b = b \\
w &= \lambda y+(1-\lambda)z \ge \lambda \cdot 0+(1-\lambda)0 = 0
\end{align}

Comment: Okay thank you, any tips on how I can do that?

Comment: Apply linearity, like you did for the objective.